# How to make an image float above the page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit an image into a `<td>` that is smaller than the actual image, but I don't want the cell to grow to accomodate the image. Instead, I want the image to float above the cell.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an element from the page structure, use absolute positioning:

```
td {position: relative;}
td img {position: absolute; top: -20px; left: -20px;}
```

Comment: I don't know the absolute position of the image. It depends on the page contents.

Comment: All Ian has done is made the `img` inside the `td` be absolutely positioned based on it's relative position inside the `td` not the`body`. If that makes sense?

Comment: On my page, it is displayed relative to the body and not the `td` as you suggest.